# Is it possible to call async in blocklistener state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to navigate to another screen when a bloc state returns success. Is there a way to await for the screens return? The code below does not work even if a added async. I'm using `flutter_bloc: ^6.1.3`  because its an old project.

```
      BlocListener<CustomerBloc, CustomerState>(
      listener: (context, state) async{
        if (state is CustomerCreateSuccessState) {
        bool res = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Card');
        }});
```

Comment: Looks apparently everything is ok, but do the following create a `void async function` and pass the listener to it, maybe it's a closure problem. Another point is that the navigation return is a nullable, should this boolean be `bool?` with type checking if you are using current sdk.

Comment: make sure the state is emitted correctly